# Is there any alternate way to preview the ANTLR generated parse tree?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, antlr, antlr4, intellij-plugin

I am using IntelliJ Idea Plugin for ANTLR v4 which previews the parse tree. But the preview is quite difficult to interpret when a large binary tree is generated in case of large code.

Is there any alternate way to view the same or generate the output in any other format like PDF etc.

[image: example for large code base]

Comment: I see there is a request for PDF format for the view in the plugin issue tracker: https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/issues/189

Comment: You also can try to generate a .dot file from parse tree with visitor and render it with https://www.graphviz.org/

Answer (score 3):

There are alternatives, if you are willing to switch tools. For example the [ANTLR4 extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4) can show an interactive parse tree (you can view it in different layouts, you can collapse nodes to hide uninteresting parts etc.). Below is a picture of the tree or watch an animation [on my homepage](http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/31-news/57-antlr4-extension-for-vscode-1-3-0-now-with-debugging-support).

[image]

This generated graph can be stored as SVG along with built-in or custom CSS to style it.

Comment: thanks, here are some links for those intersted, https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/doc/graphical-visualizations.md https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/doc/grammar-debugging.md

Answer (score 1):

Antlr provides an output of a parse tree in lisp format. `ParseTree tree = parser.yourRule()` and then output it with `tree.toString(parser)`. Then a lisp tree will be generated. You can also generate a tree in json format with Gson. However, these trees are not so 'visualized', but great for further processing.